# codeigniter session expiration refresh

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session-timeout

I have problem with sessions expiration refresh.

I do this:

```
trought -> $.ajax ({url: "/index.php/main/refresh_session"});
```

to function :

```
function refresh_session() {
   $this->session->sess_destroy();

   $data = array('is_logged_in' => true);
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
}
```

My purpose is to refresh the session timeout, but this code not works and session expires after 60 seconds. (config: $config['sess_expiration']= 60;)

Maybe someone has encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Why `$this->session->sess_destroy()` ? This function should be the last one called, and even flash variables will no longer be available. If you only want some items destroyed and not all, use unset_userdata().

Answer (score 2):

If you are adamant about calling `$this->session->sess_destroy();` then you must also call `$this->session->sess_create();` BEFORE you try to set session data again, otherwise it will not get set.

Edit: This is if you're using the database to store your sessions. Otherwise, you could re-create a session without manually calling `sess_create()`

Answer (score 1):

For the latest versions of CodeIgniter including what's currently in the 'develop' branch, you can't call `session->set_userdata` after `session->sess_destroy` as already mentioned by another answer.  This is because `sess_destroy()` clears the internal userdata array, including the current session_id which is indirectly required by `set_userdata` (set_userdata calls `sess_write` which directly requires the current `session_id`).

You should see this requirement if you have warnings enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Set `$config['sess_time_to_update']` lower than `$config['sess_expiration']`.

And remove `$this->session->sess_destroy()`. This function should be the last one called, and even flash variables will no longer be available. If you only want some items destroyed and not all, use `unset_userdata()`.

Comment: $config['sess_expiration'] = 60;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 59;

'function refresh_session() {

   $data = array('is_logged_in' => true);
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
}'


Now the session expiration not carried out at all.

Comment: Session expires after 60 seconds. Session expired time not updating :/

Answer (score 0):

```
trought -> $.ajax ({url: "/index.php/main/refresh_session"});

function refresh_session() {
   $data = array('is_logged_in' => true);
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
}
```

1. Session expiration not carried out at all:

   ```
   $config['sess_expiration'] = 60;
   $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 59;
   ```
2. Session expires after 60 seconds. Session expiration time not updating:

   ```
   $config['sess_expiration'] = 60;
   $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 5;
   $config['sess_time_to_update'] = ?
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue and after some frustrating hours of going through everything i found out i had a blank space on my index page. Removed the space and phew solved.